# Is that possible to make fake response from request interceptor?

Tags: angularjs

I want to return cached response before timeout happened and then renew cache.

I tried this:

```
.factory('TestInterceptor', TestInterceptor);

function TestInterceptor($q) {
   return {
      request: request,
      response: response
   };

   function request(config) {
      ...
       return $q.resolve(fakeResponse);
      ...
   }
   function response() {
    ....
   }
}
```

but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible. As [the manual says](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#interceptors),

> request: interceptors get called with a http config object. The function is free to modify the config object or create a new one. The function needs to return the config object directly, or a promise containing the config or a new config object.